# None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type

Tags: c++

I'm have two errors i need some help to fix

The error:

```
1>.\commands.cpp(1378) : error C2057: expected constant expression
1>.\commands.cpp(1378) : error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>.\commands.cpp(1378) : error C2133: 'buffer' : unknown size
```

The code (commands.cpp):

```
 const uint32_t changeSexPrice = g_config.getNumber(ConfigManager::CHANGESEX_PRICE);

if(money < changeSexPrice)
{
    char buffer[70 + changeSexPrice];
    sprintf(buffer, "You do not have enough money. You need %d gold coins to change your sex.", changeSexPrice);
    player->sendCancel(buffer);
    return false;
}
enter code here
```

The error:

```
luascript.cpp(1752) : error C2664: 'lua_pushcclosure' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'int32_t (__cdecl *)(lua_State *)' to 'lua_CFunction'
1>        None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
```

The code (luascript.cpp):

```
lua_register(m_luaState, "getSearchString", LuaScriptInterface::luaGetSearchString);

int32_t LuaScriptInterface::luaGetSearchString(lua_State* L)
{
//getSearchString(fromPosition, toPosition[, fromIsCreature[, toIsCreature]])
int32_t params = lua_gettop(L);
bool toIsCreature = false, fromIsCreature = false;

if(params >= 4)
    toIsCreature = popNumber(L) == LUA_TRUE;

if(params >= 3)
    fromIsCreature = popNumber(L) == LUA_TRUE;

PositionEx toPos, fromPos;
popPosition(L, toPos);
popPosition(L, fromPos);

if(toPos.x > 0 && fromPos.x > 0)
    lua_pushstring(L, g_game.getSearchString(fromPos, toPos, fromIsCreature, toIsCreature).c_str());
else
{
    reportErrorFunc("wrong position(s) specified.");
    lua_pushnumber(L, LUA_ERROR);
}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Did you define `changeSexPrice` as a constant?  The error you're getting in the C++ code is consistent with `changeSexPrice` being a regular variable.  Arrays must have their size determined at compile-time.

Comment: What is `changeSexPrice` in your first code snippet? Is it a constant? Is it a variable that's changed at runtime? Please show the definition. From that error output, I assume you are using Visual C++ compiler? Also, +1 for your use of the variable name `changeSexPrice`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your two errors are completely unrelated. Please ask about them in two separate questions so that you can get the best possible answers for each. I recommend removing the first error from this question and posting it in a new one since it doesn't match the title for this post.

Comment: By the way, it seems to me that you're using `changeSexPrice` in a contradictory way: why should an arbitrary "price" be summed to 70 to obtain the size of the buffer?

Comment: Also, which of the lines you've shown is line 1752? And the compiler says it found the error inside the `lua_pushcclosure` function, but you're showing us `luaGetSearchString`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first area change your one line from this

```
char buffer[70 + changeSexPrice]
```

to this

```
char *buffer = new char[70 + changeSexPrice]
```

And then, just before the return statement, don't forget

```
delete[] buffer;
```

For the second part, I take you are attempting to pass a pointer to this function to lua_pushcclosure in another part of the code:

```
int32_t LuaScriptInterface::luaGetSearchString(lua_State* L)
```

If that's the case, I think changing the return type to just `int` will do the trick, since `lua_cfunction is defined as

```
typedef int (*lua_CFunction) (lua_State *L);
```

**Edit**

Since we're using c++ here, this code is a very safe way to handle the buffer problem, no pointers or anything:

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream << "You do not have enought money. You need " << changeSexPrice << " gold coins to change your sex";
player->sendCancel(stream.str().c_str());
```

Comment: Actually, there is a much better way since you're dealing with c++: using string buffers. I will edit my post to show that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to account for additional characters needed to store the number, but you'd overallocate anyway, so just make that buffer reasonably big (and use `snprintf` to avoid overflows), e.g.

```
char buffer[128];
```

As for the second error, you're trying to use a member function as a C callback. That won't work. Make that function either static or completely non-member, and if you need `this` pointer, find another way to pass it through (I don't know Lua API, so can't help you with that).

Comment: All in all I'd avoid static buffers and `snprintf` completely and just use an `ostringstream`.